# Redirect JIRA url to another url

Tags: php, redirect

if you can help I will explain my issue as briefly as possible.

I have created a redirect url, so that the users can connect easier to it.

the name of the redirect is :       jira.xyz.co

the redirect is working fine, and it takes me to the desired destination url, but without DNS resolution.

http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/secure/Dashboard.jspa,

I’m trying to figure out for the redirect to have the below view after the users type: jira.xyz.co and take them to the below link

http://jira.xyz.co/jira/secure/Dashboard.jspa

I'm running jira on Ubuntu Tomcat server

I you can help or know of the solution please write back. thanks!